# Does this have an indirect object?

Tags: direct-objects, indirect-objects

> I met a kind person

As far as I know:

subject = I;
met = verb;
But seems like "kind person" is a direct object.  Is there no indirect object?

Comment: I met him an hour prior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  There is no indirect object.  The verb *to meet* does not lend itself to an indirect object.  Here is simple example of the indirect object.   I give you food.  *Food* is the direct object and *you* is the indirect object.